# Accessing MSN weather api using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

This is the URL I'm using but I couldn't find a way to access this using any method of jQuery.

http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?src=vista&weadegreetype=C&culture=tr-TR&wealocations=wc%3a1885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know jquery can only retrieve files from your own server. However there are ways around this if you have access to a Server side scripting language such as PHP and by harnessing the power of ajax.

See http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

For a way to do what you want using both jQuery and PHP

(This depends on the server settings of the domain where the file is located).

Comment: I will use Yahoo's weather api with YQL and it supports JSONP so that I can use it without PHP proxy file. Thanks anyway George.

Answer (score 0):

We are writing to notify you that the Microsoft Weather API will no longer be available for download and will be discontinued as of April 15, 2015, meaning it will no longer provide weather data.  Accordingly, please remove the Microsoft Weather API from any of your products or apps that currently use it.

Here is a list of external providers who might be able to support your needs if you are interested in obtaining an alternate weather API:

```
http://api.accuweather.com/ 
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html 
https://developer.forecast.io/
```

Disclaimer:  Microsoft and Microsoft Weather are not affiliated or associated with any of the above companies in any way.

Thank You 
Microsoft Weather Team